# Overly slow Ruby script

Tags: ruby

Well, the first thing I do is extract the hexadecimals from a file and I write them in a .txt (it takes less than 1 second) then is when I pass this script to separate them into groups of 4 hexadecimals:

```
txt1 = 'HEX.txt'

count = 0
File.foreach(txt1).with_index do |line| 
    line.each_char do |hex|
        count += 1
        File.open('out1.txt', 'a') do |f|
            f.write(hex)
            if count == 4
                f.write(' ')
                count = 0
            end           
        end
    end
end
```

But it takes too long being that the .txt with the hexadecimal only weighs 13MB so I think this script is very bad how can I improve it?

Comment: You're calling with_index, but don't seem to use the index at all. You could drop that for a start

Comment: there is a lot of room for improvement (`each_slice` for example). But I see the biggest Problem in `File.open`. Since this is in the loop, the program will open and close the File for every char. 

But mostly, why? displaying the space between columns in hex is a job for the editor/viewer not for the file

Comment: Best practice would be to simply `puts` the result. The user can redirect that to a file if desired.

Comment: Presumably, you are initially reading from a binary file. If so, how did you decide to break up that file into `n` pieces to create a text file with `n` lines?

Comment: It would be a great help if you gave a small example of what the text file you have produced looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
write_string = 
  File.open(txt1) do |f| 
    f.readlines.map { |line| line.scan(/.{1,4}/) }.join(' ')
  end

File.open('out1.txt', 'a') do |f|
  f.write(write_string)
end
```

We can regex scan each line to break the line into groups of 4. Then we only need the one join outside the map to condense everything into one string of groups of 4 characters.

I think that opening and writing to the file every character is the source of the slow down.  Now we have one write for the whole file.

EDIT: Tested the scan vs gsub idea from the comments.

`file_name = 'test_file.txt'`

`File.open(file_name, 'a') { |f| f.puts(('a' * 200 * 1000).scan(/.{200}/)) }`

Gives us a file of 1000 lines made of 200 (50 * 4) characters per line. I used scan in file creation, but it's not part of the test! :)

```
Benchmark.bmbm do |x| 
  x.report(:scan) do 
    File.open(file_name) do |f| 
      f.readlines.map { |line| line.scan(/.{1,4}/) }.join(' ')
    end
  end
  x.report(:gsub) do 
    File.open(file_name) do |f| 
      f.readlines.map { |line| line.gsub(/(.{4})(?=\S)/, "\\1 ") }.join(' ') 
    end
  end
end

         user     system      total        real
scan   0.020217   0.000273   0.020490 (  0.020522)
gsub   0.035371   0.000603   0.035974 (  0.035975)

scan   0.020094   0.000164   0.020258 (  0.020275)
gsub   0.034890   0.000528   0.035418 (  0.035442)
```

Looks like scan is about 43% faster.

Comment: I wonder if my variant `.gsub(/(.{4})(?=\S)/, "\\1 ")` faster or slower?

Comment: This is the first answer which does not use `each_char`. So this is the way to go.  However the `scan` command will return chunks. Like this I think not that the regex saves any time compared to `each_slice` since index based slicing shouldn't be to slow. 
But If you use a gsub ruby don't needs to slice the array into chunks. This will be faster. (Ignore what I said before in the comment, I am pretty sure `gsub` will be faster)

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I updated with some Benchmarks.  Looks like scan is the faster of the two!  I have no idea of the forces at play here, though.

Comment: Thank you really much Tom that's very interesting.

Comment: `IO::foreach` would be preferable over `::readlines`. Right Now this is `File` => `Array`(readlines) => `Array`(map) => `String`(join). Atleast `foreach` could be `File` => `Enumerator`(foreach) => `Array` (map) => `String`. However that is still a large `Array` and a large `String`. Thus nested loops with enumerators would probably be the most efficient to essentially stream the data in chunks from file to file

Comment: Your script takes 21 Seconds, It is the fastest of all so I choose it as the best answer, thanks.